# UIView Responsabilities (Object-Oriented Programming)

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, oop, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am just starting out with iOS app development and it's been a great experience so far. Apple documentation is great, but there are some questions I have that are not as technical and only someone with experience might be able to answer.

I have a bunch of UIViewController which handle the "dynamic skinning" of the custom UIViews that they control. This leads to a controller with big chunks of code which seems a bit unpractical to me.

So the question is: Following the MVC pattern, should I give the responsibility of setting a UIFont, UIColor, etc to the view itself? Or should I create "micro" controllers that handle this task using some kind of input?

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating `UIView` subclasses that handle the layout works. Override `layoutSubviews` in the `UIView` subclass to do the positioning layout (setting frames etc). I find the `init` method to be a good place to set fonts, colors etc.

Now the `UIViewController` has relatively little code related to the custom UIView. The viewController just needs to position an instance of the custom UIView and perhaps set a few properties (like a textLabel's text).